# SQL Server Pivoting like HBase

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have a big historized key-value store in the following form:

```
╔════════════╦═══════════════╦════════╦════════════╗
║ Product_ID ║ Key           ║ Value  ║    Date    ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════╬════════╬════════════╣
║          1 ║ Brand         ║ Foo    ║ 01.11.2017 ║
║          1 ║ Product Group ║ Health ║ 02.11.2017 ║
║          1 ║ Brand         ║ Bar    ║ 07.11.2017 ║
╚════════════╩═══════════════╩════════╩════════════╝
```

Now I need to transpose that table into a pivot like structure with Product_ID and Date as rows and the keys as columns. But... preserving any old data if they are not updated.

This is perfectly done in HBase where someone can store billions of rows and millions of columns. It just shows the last valid data for a specific date in the past, although they are not updated at that time.

So the result should look something like the following.

```
╔════════════╦════════════╦═══════╦═══════════════╗
║ Product_ID ║    Date    ║ Brand ║ Product Group ║
╠════════════╬════════════╬═══════╬═══════════════╣
║          1 ║ 01.11.2017 ║ Foo   ║ NULL          ║
║          1 ║ 02.11.2017 ║ Foo   ║ Health        ║
║          1 ║ 07.11.2017 ║ Bar   ║ Health        ║
╚════════════╩════════════╩═══════╩═══════════════╝
```

As you can see, for the 02.11.2017 the Brand and for the 07.11.2017 Health is taken from the previous row. Persisting data over time.

Did somebody came across such a request or is heavily working with key-value stores and have a pointer how it might work?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach by using `case` expression if you don't want to go `pivot`

```
;with cte as
(SELECT Product_ID,
       [Date],
      CASE ([Key]) when 'Brand' then Value END      [Brand],
      CASE ([Key]) when 'Product Group' then Value END      [Product Group],
      row_number() over (order by (select 1)) rn FROM <table_name>),
      cte1 as 
      (
       SELECT Product_ID, [Date],
        CASE ([Key]) when 'Brand' then Value END      [Brand],
        CASE ([Key]) when 'Product Group' then Value END      [Product Group],
      row_number() over (order by (select 1)) rn
       FROM <table_name>
      )
SELECT
       T.Product_ID,
       T.[Date]
  ,CASE WHEN
    T.Brand IS NULL THEN
        (SELECT TOP 1 Brand FROM cte1 WHERE rn<T.rn AND Brand IS NOT NULL ORDER BY rn DESC)
    ELSE T.Brand
END AS Brand
,CASE WHEN
    T.[Product Grou] IS NULL THEN
        (SELECT TOP 1 [Product Group] FROM cte1 WHERE rn<T.rn AND [Product Group] IS NOT NULL ORDER BY rn DESC)
    ELSE T.[Product Grou]
END AS [Product Group]
FROM cte T
```

Result :

```
Product_ID  Date        Brand   Product Group
1           01.11.2017  Foo     NULL
1           02.11.2017  Foo     Health
1           07.11.2017  Bar     Health
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution. Highly appreciated!